# which is a better design for database status values?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I see some people design design their database having a column STATUS INT where they add values like 0- not active, 1-active, 2-pending . What is the difference between just making an enum('not active','active','pending'). Is it a better database design to not have strings defined for fields and use integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If option are limited and fix use enum with direct `('not active','active','pending')`

Otherwise it will be better to make child table for options and store corresponding integer id(`Primary key` of child table) in parent table.