# Is ENUM really evil (SHOW COLUMNS or SELECT)?

Tags: php, mysql

is better to use ENUM or separate table to get list from possible values (eg html select)?

What is better practice?

when i use SHOW COLUMNS, enum type must by parsed;

OR

when i use separate table to store possible values and use SELECT * ???

Comment: Sorry, what? It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239137/which-is-a-better-design-for-database-status-values/9239163#9239163

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use enum, you are actually hardcode your list in the database table. So if you need to add something you will need to go and alter the table. On the other hand, when you use a table that you are connecting it through foreighn key, you can add easily a keyword (choice) from the front end application without the need to alter your schema.

I prefer to use enum when the choices are not subject to change and the table with the foreign key relationship when my list is changing over time. Choice is yours.

I hope that this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: 'it depends'.

It depends on whether you expect the list of those values to be never (or very rarely) changed, or to be changing frequently.

In the first case, it makes sense to create an ENUM as it defines the list of values as part of data model itself. It explicitly tells the user, what values are allowed.

In the latter case, we deal with data rather than with data model, so it's both more sensible and practical, to have a separate table for these values.

Answer (score 0):

It is really depends on number of options you are planning to store. If there are only 3, I would suggest to use UNUM, otherwise separated table is better. Second table better also if you are going to add more options in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If option are limited and fix use enum with direct ('not active','active','pending')

Otherwise it will be better to make child table for options and store corresponding integer id(Primary key of child table) in parent table.

Refer My Answer :
[which is a better design for database status values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239137/which-is-a-better-design-for-database-status-values/9239163#9239163)